# PHP Contact Form does not work when I add $name

Tags: php

Having a strange issue with my contact form.  For some reason my code works fine if I do not have the $name tag in my code.  It has to be something simple I am missing! Here is my code:

```html
<?php

    $error = ""; $successMessage = "";

    if ($_POST) {
        
        if (!$_POST["email"]) {
            
            $error .= "An email address is required.<br>";
            
        }
        
        if (!$_POST["content"]) {
            
            $error .= "The content field is required.<br>";
            
        }
        
        if (!$_POST["subject"]) {
            
            $error .= "The subject is required.<br>";
            
        }
        
        if ($_POST['email'] && filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
            
            $error .= "The email address is invalid.<br>";
            
        }
      
        if (!$_POST["name"]) {
            
            $error .= "Full name is required.<br>";
            
        }
        
        if ($error != "") {
            
            $error = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><p>There were error(s) in your form:</p>' . $error . '</div>';
            
        } else {
          
           $name = $_POST['name'];
            
            $emailTo = "name@example.com";
            
            $subject = $_POST['subject'];
            
            $content = $_POST['content'];
            
            $headers = 'From: '.$_POST['name'].' <'.$_POST['email'].">\r\n";
            
            if (mail($name, $emailTo, $subject, $content, $headers)) {
                
                echo "<script>alert('Message Sent Successfully');</script>";
                 echo "<script>window.location = 'index.php';</script>";
                
            } else {
                
                $error = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><p><strong>Your message couldn\'t be sent - please try again later</div>';
                
                
            }
            
        }
        
        
        
    }

?>
```

It works fine if I just have subject, email, and content.  Here is my code for that:

```html
<?php

    $error = ""; $successMessage = "";

    if ($_POST) {
        
        if (!$_POST["email"]) {
            
            $error .= "An email address is required.<br>";
            
        }
        
        if (!$_POST["content"]) {
            
            $error .= "The content field is required.<br>";
            
        }
        
        if (!$_POST["subject"]) {
            
            $error .= "The subject is required.<br>";
            
        }
        
        if ($_POST['email'] && filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
            
            $error .= "The email address is invalid.<br>";
            
        }
        
        if ($error != "") {
            
            $error = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><p>There were error(s) in your form:</p>' . $error . '</div>';
            
        } else {
            
            $emailTo = "me@mydomain.com";
            
            $subject = $_POST['subject'];
            
            $content = $_POST['content'];
            
            $headers = "From: ".$_POST['email'];
            
            if (mail($emailTo, $subject, $content, $headers)) {
                
                 echo "<script>alert('Message Sent Successfully');</script>";
                 echo "<script>window.location = 'index.php';</script>";
                
                
            } else {
                
                $error = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><p><strong>Your message couldn\'t be sent - please try again later</div>';
                
                
            }
            
        }
        
        
        
    }

?>
```

Hopefully someone can see where I went wrong.
Thanks!

Comment: Look at the parameters of the `mail` function. I think the issue will be immediately clear. (parameter 1 is `to`, 2 is `subject`, 3 is `body`, 4 is `headers`).

Comment: you have entered wrong parameters in mail function. you can check it over here.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php/

Comment: Ah so simple! Totally missed that one.  Thank you! It works perfect now

Comment: `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` does not work properly.